# Bootstrap 5 Toast element not found on Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

Using Rails 7. I am trying to get Bootstrap 5 Toast to work on the Rails flash message / notice message. Here's my code:

```
# application.html.erb
<head>
...
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
<script>
    const toastElList = document.querySelectorAll('.toast')
    const toastList = [...toastElList].map(toastEl => new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl))
    console.log(toastElList);
</script>
</head>

<div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
  <div id="liveToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-header">
      <img src="..." class="rounded me-2" alt="...">
      <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
      <small>11 mins ago</small>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      Hello, world! This is a toast message.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...

# application.js
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
```

I can confirm that Bootstrap Javascript is working on my Rails app because the dropdown menu works.

I hardcoded the `.toast` element to test. In the `console.log(toastElList)` it is empty, no element seems to be found.

How do I make this Toast show and hide automatically?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? What is `option`?

Comment: @mykaf Sorry typo. Removed option. No error.

Answer (score 0):

I was a dumbass. So since elements couldn't be found, that's because the window wasn't loaded. Here's the change:

```
<script>
  window.onload = (event) => {
    const toastElList = document.querySelectorAll('.toast')
    const toastList = [...toastElList].map(toastEl => new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl))
    console.log(toastElList);
  };
</script>
```

With `window.onload`, the elements are now found.